# linking problem with react-native-vector-icons

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am using xcode 10, React-Native 0.60.

I know rn 0.60 has autolinking feature but it is not applicable on rn-vector-icons. when i manually link this package xcode throws an error and says

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/alkanv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Circle-bnmddodmnsbyriecdpuymeenohdn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Circle.app/Foundation.ttf':
1) Target 'Circle' (project 'Circle') has copy command from '/Users/alkanv/Circle/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Foundation.ttf' to '/Users/alkanv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Circle-bnmddodmnsbyriecdpuymeenohdn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Circle.app/Foundation.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'Circle' (project 'Circle'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

it gives this error for every single icon file listed in `Build Phahes -> Copy Bundle Resources` section. when i search this problem, people say that solution is delete those icon files from bundle resources section. However, when i delete .ttf files from there, it build successfully BUT, this time React Native throw an error and says:
`Unrecognized font family Material Icons`
Btw, this is not about Material Icon, if i try to put there FontAwesome it throws same error for it too.

I lost like half of a day on this so any help will be appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**

I fix the problem.

unlink package,
delete npm package,
install it again.
link it again, install pod.
navigate to info.plist file add which font class you want to use into `fonts provided for the application`, delete all listed files related with vector-icons in `Build Phahes -> Copy Bundle Resources`

if this does not help, install react-native-config, create a file called `react-native.config.js` in project's root folder.

add this line to that file :

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-vector-icons': {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```